# How do you perform seperate queries on different fields in Solr using the Extended DisMax QueryParser?

Tags: java, mysql, solr, lucene

I would like to query Solr using the edismax query parser on two fields with seperate queries.

My Solr schema contains 2 field "title" and "text"
I want to query the "title" field for say "Java" and not "Javascript"
and query the "text" field for say "Hello World"

Using the standard "lucene" query parser, it would look like
title:(java AND NOT javascript) AND text:(hello AND world). How do you do this using the "edismax" query parser?

Answer (score 0):

```
q=title:(java AND NOT javascript) AND text:(hello AND world)
```

will work. Edismax parser supports Lucene syntax. Add debugQuery=true to your request and you will see parsedQuery dos not contain a DisjunctionMaxQuery like a typical edismax query will.